# OR operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions

Tags: apex, soql, community, record-type

I got a requirement like to calculate average in account based on particular record type of case. My requirement is:

I have a field called ARP in account number. I want to calculate overall average of ARP field in particular record type called customer order whether Case details either new or add-on.

So I'm trying write a trigger to filter record on case as per above said. But it throws this error:

> OR can't be applied on boolean expressions.

```
trigger ForARPU on Case (after insert,after update,after delete) 
{
    Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Order'].Id;
    List<Case> CaseIDs = new List<Case>();
    for (Case s : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId ) 
        {
            if(s.Case_Details__c ='New Subscription' || s.Case_Details__c ='Add On') 
            {
            CaseIDs.add(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I have to filter first ids then I go another if condition for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluate equality using double equals (`==`). Use of a single equals sign (`=`) means assignment.

```
Boolean isNewSubscription = s.Case_Details == 'New Subscription';
```

You can also use `equalsIgnoreCase` (double equals comparison is case-insensitive) or just `equals` if you want to make the comparison case-sensitive. Make sure you put the value you know to be non-null first if you use one of these methods.

```
Boolean isNewSubscription = 'New Subscription'.equalsIgnoreCase(s.Case_Details);
```